# Distribute A huge list of elements into list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Lets say, I have a huge list consisting of phone, email, web address, They belong to particular organization/company/person. Number of phone, email or web address will vary. Some might not have a phone number or email etc.

```
a_list = [
 "+99112233",
 "+39383",     
 "www.johndoe.com",
 "info@JohnDoe.com".
 "+9933933",
 "+99883399",
 "www.someother.com",
 "www.tt.com"
 "support@tt.com",
 "info@tt.com",
]
```

I want to group them in a dict like:

```
contacts = [
{ 'phones': ["+99112233", "+39383"],
  'websites': ["www.johndoe.com"],
  'emails': ['info@JohnDoe.com'],

},
{
'phones': ["+9933933","+99883399"], 
'websites': ['www.someother.com'],
'emails': []
},
{
'phones': [], 
'websites': ['www.tt.com'],
'emails': ['support@tt.com', 'info@tt.com']
}
]
```

this is my code so far:

```
push_flag = False
contacts = []
phones = []
emails = []
webs  =   []
for contact in a_list:
    text = contact
    if text[0]== "+":
       if push_flag:
            contacts.append({
                'phones': phones,
                'webs': webs,
                'emails':emails,
             })
             phones = []
             webs = []
             emails = []
             push_flag = False
        phones.append(text)
    elif text[0:3]=="www":
        push_flag = True
        webs.append(text)
    elif "@" in text:
        push_flag = True
        emails.append(text)

contacts.append({
            'phones': phones,
            'webs': webs,
            'emails':emails,
            })
```

Comment: What's the problem in your code?

Comment: Why is the resultant `list` contain 3 `dicts`? Cant it be a single dictionary?

Comment: 3 dicts mean they belong to three different company/person/organizations

Comment: push_flag : you used this variable before assignment

Comment: I smell an XY-problem, where did `a_list` come from? Probably you could have parsed it better originally

Comment: @Harsha It won't work for those memberrs who don't have any phone numbers

Comment: How can I categorize if 2 of the values from phone, webs and emails are missing? After phone number, if webs and emails are missing and next phone comes in list, how can we categorize that these numbers should be in 2 different dict? Is there like any 2 fields are compulsory?

Comment: Yes, at least two fields will appear for each person and there is a sequence phones, webs, emails for each person. @Harsha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things might help you simplify the logic here. First, I'd use a list of regex-category pairs in order to identify whether each element is a phone number, website, or email address. This approach is nice because it will allow you to add other data easily without having to mess with the structure of your parsing code. Second, a `defaultdict(list)` seems like a really appropriate structure for each contact.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from more_itertools import peekable

category_pairs = [
    (re.compile('^\+[0-9]+$'), 'phones'),
    (re.compile('^www\..*?\.[A-Za-z]+$'), 'websites'),
    (re.compile('^.+?@.+\.[A-Za-z]+$'), 'emails'),
]

contacts = []
current = defaultdict(list)
iterator = peekable(a_list)
entry = next(iterator)

while iterator.peek(False):
    for regex, category in category_pairs:
        while regex.match(entry):
            current[category].append(entry)
            if not iterator.peek(False):
                break
            entry = next(iterator)
    contacts.append(current)
    current = defaultdict(list)
```

This code makes one assumption: that the phone numbers, website, and email address occur in that order and groups them as such.

Comment: Neat! I liked the use of [more-itertools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
a_list = [
 "+99112233",
 "+39383",     
 "www.johndoe.com",
 "info@JohnDoe.com",
 "+9933933",
 "+99883399",
 "www.someother.com",
 "www.tt.com",
 "support@tt.com",
 "info@tt.com",
]


contacts = []
contact_dict ={}

len_of_list = len(a_list)
for index,contact in enumerate(a_list):
    if index==0:
        contact_dict["phones"] = [contact]
        continue

    if (a_list[index])[0] == "+":
        if (a_list[index-1])[0] == "+" :
            contact_dict["phones"].append(contact)
        else:
            contacts.append(contact_dict)
            contact_dict ={}
            contact_dict["phones"] = [contact]

    if contact[0:3]=="www":
        if (a_list[index-1])[0:3] == "www" :
            contact_dict["email"] = []
            contacts.append(contact_dict)
            contact_dict ={}
            contact_dict["website"] = [contact]
            contact_dict["phone"] =[]
        else:
            contact_dict["website"] = [contact]

    if "@" in contact:
        if "@" in (a_list[index-1]):
            contact_dict["email"].append(contact)
        else:
            contact_dict["email"] = [contact]

    if index == len_of_list-1:
        contacts.append(contact_dict)          

print(contacts)
```

Output:

```
[{
    'website': ['www.johndoe.com'],
    'phones': ['+99112233', '+39383'],
    'email': ['info@JohnDoe.com']
}, {
    'website': ['www.someother.com'],
    'phones': ['+9933933', '+99883399'],
    'email': []
}, {
    'website': ['www.tt.com'],
    'phone': [],
    'email': ['support@tt.com', 'info@tt.com']
}]
```